# Limit of a linear operator

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear operator with norm less than one.
I need to show that
$$
\|A^n v\| \rightarrow 0 \quad\text{for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$}
$$
My idea was to somehow show that  $\| A^n v \| \leq  \|  A v \|^n$ but I have not been able to do this.

Comment: What is the definition of the norm of an operator? $1 > \lVert A \rVert = \ldots $

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$||A^nv|| = ||A(A^{n-1} v)|| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||A^{n-1} v|| \leq \cdots \leq ||A||^{n-1} ||Av|| \leq ||A||^n ||v||$